# How to use more than 1 quotation using getRows method and .implode in sql Query, using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get all records from db using getRows method, to achieve that I need to implode special characters.

In previous function, to get $ids I used:

```
foreach ($ids as &$id) $id = (int)$id;
        $rows = $this->db->getRows('SELECT name, id FROM database WHERE id IN ('.implode(',', $ids).')');
        if (count($rows)) {
            foreach ($rows as $row) 
            {
                $ret[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
            }
        }
```

but in my next function I need to use **name** to search for records.

Because name is in single quotes `'name'`  I tried making it like this:

```
foreach ($names as $name) $id=(int)$name;
        $rows = $this->db->getRows('SELECT name, is_active FROM database WHERE name IN ('.implode(',',$names).')');
        if(count($rows))
            {
                foreach ($rows as $row)
                {
                    $ret[$row['name']] = $row['is_active'];
                }
            }
```

it doesnt solve the problem, it just crashes. So I tried changing it a bit with separating it with double quotes:

```
$rows = $this->db->getRows("SELECT name, is_active FROM database WHERE name IN (" .implode(',',$names) .")");
```

still getting same error `database query error`.

and I dont know really what to do next. I believe I cant pass that many quotes inside of a implode.
Query should look like this: `SELECT name, is_active FROM database WHERE name IN ('name1', 'name2', 'name3')`

I tried to follow [PHP: implode - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) with same error results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching between single or double quotes like you did, doesn't change the fact that you did not add any quotes around the individual name values at all. These quotes are the string delimiters the PHP syntax requires, but you have not added any quotes around the names in your implode yet, which the SQL syntax requires.

And implode only inserts the separator *between* the values - so the quote character before the first, and the quote character after the last item, still need to be added.

You want something like

```
'SELECT name, is_active FROM database WHERE name IN ("'.implode('","',$names).'")'
```

which will produce

```
SELECT name, is_active FROM database WHERE name IN ("a","b","c")
```

Comment: And you should of course not insert the names into the query untreated, that opens you up to the possibility of SQL injection. The fact alone, that you are still not using _prepared statements_ in 2022, makes what you are doing quite anachronistic.

Comment: Yes, I know I didn't, that's really what my question is about. I tried doing it using .include(' ',' ',$names). But there is so many quotes that it probably doesn't see it. As far as I have been instructed, I updated $name to id to prevent from sql injection.

Comment: _"I tried doing it using `.include(' ',' ',$names).`"_ - you mean implode, not include.  And it does not make sense, because with this, you would be passing _three_ parameters to implode, instead of the two it wants. But what exactly is not working with the line exactly as I showed it?

Comment: _"As far as I have been instructed, I updated $name to id to prevent from sql injection"_ - that does not have _anything_ to do with preventing SQL injection.

Comment: I updated it to match single quotes: `$rows = $this->db->getRows('SELECT name, is_active FROM networks WHERE name IN ('.implode("','",$names).')');` With same db query error

Comment: Why don't you _check_ what SQL query this actually produces? If you were to echo that string value, you could clearly see what is wrong: https://3v4l.org/1PTOB I did explicitly say _"the quote character before the first, and the quote character after the last item, still need to be added"_, did I not?

Comment: Now I understand, this online php editor is miracle. Thanks you!